# Border Type in a view's border (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiview, border

do you know if is it possible to apply a border type in a view?

I can do this

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

But I don't know how to apply different borders (- - - - -, ---------, etc) to my view. How can I do it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: this topic resolves your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184133/add-a-border-of-a-uiview-instead-of-in-a-view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want custom borders, you'll need to draw them yourself in `-drawRect:`.