# UIBezierPath: How to add a border around a view with rounded corners?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I am using UIBezierPath to have my imageview have round corners but I also want to add a border to the imageview. Keep in mind the top is a uiimage and the bottom is a label.

Currently using this code produces:

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = myCell2.NewFeedImageView.frame
rectShape.position = myCell2.NewFeedImageView.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myCell2.NewFeedImageView.bounds,
    byRoundingCorners: .TopRight | .TopLeft,
    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)).CGPath
myCell2.NewFeedImageView.layer.mask = rectShape
```

[image: current]

I want to add a green border to that but I cant use

```
myCell2.NewFeedImageView.layer.borderWidth = 8
myCell2.NewFeedImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
```

because it cuts off the top left and top right corner of the border as seen in this image:

[image: issue]

Is there a way too add in a border with UIBezierPath along with my current code?

Comment: it's really not that easy to do this - in my answer below, I try to address the unfortunate subtleties involved.

Comment: hi @gooberboobbutt !  do you think you could tick my answer after all this time!  thanks!  :)

Comment: howdy @gooberboobbutt - put in a perfect modern solution for 2019  :)  Enjoy

Answer (score 64):

You can reuse the UIBezierPath path and add a shape layer to the view. Here is an example inside a view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a view with red background for demonstration
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        v.center = view.center
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(v)

        // Add rounded corners
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = v.bounds
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: v.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .TopRight | .TopLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)).CGPath
        v.layer.mask = maskLayer

        // Add border
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path // Reuse the Bezier path
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 5
        borderLayer.frame = v.bounds
        v.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)   
    }

}
```

The end result looks like this.

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Note that this only works as expected when the view's size is fixed. When the view can resize, you will need to create a custom view class and resize the layers in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: ````path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopRight,  .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)).CGPath
````

Answer (score 9):

### Older 2017 solution:

Scroll down for the modern solution.

As it says above:

### It is not easy to do this perfectly.

Here's a drop-in solution.

---

This

- correctly addresses the issue that you are drawing ***HALF*** OF THE BORDER LINE
- is totally usable in autolayout
- completely re-works itself when the size of the view changes **or animates**

for 2019 ...

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedCornersAndTrueBorder: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10 {
        didSet { setup() }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet { setup() }
    }
    @IBInspectable var trueBorderWidth: CGFloat = 2.0 {
        didSet { setup() }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    
    var border:CAShapeLayer? = nil
    
    func setup() {
        // make a path with round corners
        let path = UIBezierPath(
          roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius:cornerRadius)
        
        // note that it is >exactly< the size of the whole view
        
        // mask the whole view to that shape
        // note that you will ALSO be masking the border we'll draw below
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        
        // add another layer, which will be the border as such
        
        if (border == nil) {
            border = CAShapeLayer()
            self.layer.addSublayer(border!)
        }
        // IN SOME APPROACHES YOU would INSET THE FRAME
        // of the border-drawing layer by the width of the border
        // border.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: borderWidth, dy: borderWidth)
        // so that when you draw the line, ALL of the WIDTH of the line
        // DOES fall within the actual mask.
        
        // here, we will draw the border-line LITERALLY ON THE EDGE
        // of the path. that means >HALF< THE LINE will be INSIDE
        // the path and HALF THE LINE WILL BE OUTSIDE the path
        border!.frame = bounds
        let pathUsingCorrectInsetIfAny =
          UIBezierPath(roundedRect: border!.bounds, cornerRadius:cornerRadius)
        
        border!.path = pathUsingCorrectInsetIfAny.cgPath
        border!.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        // the following is not what you want:
        // it results in "half-missing corners"
        // (note however, sometimes you do use this approach):
        //border.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        //border.borderWidth = borderWidth
        
        // this approach will indeed be "inside" the path:
        border!.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        border!.lineWidth = trueBorderWidth * 2.0
        // HALF THE LINE will be INSIDE the path and HALF THE LINE
        // WILL BE OUTSIDE the path. so MAKE IT >>TWICE AS THICK<<
        // as requested by the consumer class.
        
    }
}
```

So that's it.

(Minor aside - recall, IBDesignable is completely broken (2023) in Xcode storyboard, so, as with any IBDesignable, you won't "see it on storyboard".)

---

### Beginner help for the question in the comments ...

1. Make a "new Swift file" called "Fattie.swift".  (Note, funnily enough it actually makes no difference what you call it.  If you are at the stage of "don't know how to make a new file" seek basic Xcode tutorials.)
2. Put all of the above code in the file
3. You've just added a class "RoundedCornersAndTrueBorder" to your project.
4. On your story board.  Add an *ordinary UIView to your scene*.  In fact, make it actually any size/shape whatsoever, anything you prefer.
5. Look at the *Identity Inspector*. (If you do not know what that is, seek basic tutorials.) Simply change the class to "RoundedCornersAndTrueBorder".  (Once you start typing "Roun...", it will guess which class you mean.
6. You're done - run the project.

Note that you have to, of course, add complete and correct constraints to the UIView, just as with absolutely anything you do in Xcode.  Enjoy!

Similar solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465440/294884 - image + rounded + shadows
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553784/294884 - two-corner problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884 - "shadows + hole" or "glowbox" problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57400842/294884 - the "border AND gap" problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57514286/294884 - basic "adding" beziers

And please also see the alternate answer below!  :)

Comment: how do we use this to create a border? Sorry, if my question is too naive. :-/

Comment: Hey @Fattie, thanks so much for that detailed explanation. Well, I'm slightly better than that. But, thanks again for taking time to help me out. Sure, it would be of help to many more. But, the reason I came looking for was different. I have a UITextView that I need a border, but I don't want to use the available methods. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess this is experience! I was trying to do a workaround, and you were like, "Just do this". Awesome! Thanks. But, I'd use my solution for the time-being. Gives me a special feeling. But, thanks again!

Comment: thank you that was the only solution that worked for XCode 9.2 beta.

Comment: @Shyam - ciao - I put in a better, more up to date, solution as a new answer. Enjoy!  :)

Answer (score 4):

## Absolutely perfect 2019 solution:

[image]

Without further ado, here's exactly how you do this.

1. Don't actually use, in any way, the "standard" layer `.layer` that comes with the view
2. Make a new layer *only for* the image. You can now mask this (circularly) without affecting the next layer
3. Make a new layer for the border as such. It will safely not be masked by the picture layer.
4. It is ridiculously tricky to do the arithmetic for the radii matching perfectly.

The key facts are

1. With a CALayer, you can indeed apply a MASK as such ***and it only affects that layer***.
2. When drawing a circle (or indeed any border), have to attend very carefully to the fact that you only get "half the width" - in short ***never*** crop using the ***same*** path you ***draw*** with.
3. Notice the original cat image is exactly as wide as the horizontal yellow arrow. You have to be careful to paint the image so that the ***whole*** image appears in the roundel, ***which is smaller than*** the overall custom control.

So, setup in the usual way

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GreenCirclePerson: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.black { didSet { setup() } }
    @IBInspectable var trueBorderThickness: CGFloat = 2.0 { didSet { setup() } }
    @IBInspectable var trueGapThickness: CGFloat = 2.0 { didSet { setup() } }
    
    @IBInspectable var picture: UIImage? = nil { didSet { setup() } }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
         super.layoutSubviews()
         setup()
    }
    
    var imageLayer: CALayer? = nil
    var border: CAShapeLayer? = nil
    
    func setup() {
        
        if (imageLayer == nil) {
            imageLayer = CALayer()
            self.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer!)
        }
        if (border == nil) {
            border = CAShapeLayer()
            self.layer.addSublayer(border!)
        }
```

Now carefully make the layer for the circularly-cropped image:

```
        // the ultimate size of our custom control:
        let box = self.bounds.aspectFit()
        
        let totalInsetOnAnyOneSide = trueBorderThickness + trueGapThickness
        
        let boxInWhichImageSits = box.inset(by:
           UIEdgeInsets(top: totalInsetOnAnyOneSide, left: totalInsetOnAnyOneSide,
           bottom: totalInsetOnAnyOneSide, right: totalInsetOnAnyOneSide))
        
        // just a note. that version of inset#by is much clearer than the
        // confusing dx/dy variant, so best to use that one
        
        imageLayer!.frame = boxInWhichImageSits
        imageLayer!.contents = picture?.cgImage
        imageLayer?.contentsGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        let halfImageSize = boxInWhichImageSits.width / 2.0
        
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: imageLayer!.bounds,
           cornerRadius:halfImageSize)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        imageLayer!.mask = maskLayer
```

Next as a completely separate layer, draw the border as you wish:

```
        // now create the border
        
        border!.frame = bounds
        
        // To draw the border, you must inset it by half the width of the border,
        // otherwise you'll be drawing only half the border. (Indeed, as an additional
        // subtle problem you are clipping rather than rendering the outside edge.)
        
        let halfWidth = trueBorderThickness / 2.0
        let borderCenterlineBox = box.inset(by:
            UIEdgeInsets(top: halfWidth, left: halfWidth,
            bottom: halfWidth, right: halfWidth))
        
        let halfBorderBoxSize = borderCenterlineBox.width / 2.0
        
        let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: borderCenterlineBox,
          cornerRadius:halfBorderBoxSize)
        
        border!.path = borderPath.cgPath
        border!.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        border!.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        border!.lineWidth = trueBorderThickness
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly as in iOS standard controls:

[image]

Everything which is invisible is invisible; you can see-through the overall custom control to any material behind, there are no "half thickness" problems or missing image material, you can set the custom control background color in the usual way, etc etc. The inspector controls all work properly. (Phew!)

As a footnote, you'd (of course) write this using lazy var idioms as with any custom control; I wrote it as above for didactic reason, it shows the flow of the thinking.

Similar solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465440/294884 - image + rounded + shadows
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553784/294884 - two-corner problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884 - "shadows + hole" or "glowbox" problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57400842/294884 - the "border AND gap" problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57514286/294884 - basic "adding" beziers

Answer (score 0):

There sure is! Every view has a `layer` property (which you know from giving your layer rounded corners). Another two properties on `layer` are `borderColor` and `borderWidth`. Just by setting those you can add a border to your view! (The border will follow the rounded corners.) Be sure to use `UIColor.CGColor` for `borderColor` as a plain `UIColor` won't match the type.

Comment: How do I add it into the code? I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.

Comment: I know how that feels! rectShape.borderWidth = 3 and rectShape.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor That should do that trick!

Comment: But I see that you're already doing that. A simple fix would be to make the image inside of the green card a little smaller.

Comment: the top is a uiimage and the bottom is a label so that isnt going to work

Comment: Have you considered adding both the UIImage and the UILabel as subviews inside of a container UIView? That way you could make the UIImage's width a little smaller than the containing view and position the label inside of the view. Round the view's corners, give it a border and a you're good to go. Let me know if you have questions about how to do that!

Comment: I ended up adding a label over it and adding a border to that thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
**use this extension for round borders and corner**



       
       
    
 extension UIView {

   func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
    
    func roundCornersWithBorder(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
        
        layer.mask = maskLayer
        
        // Add border
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path // Reuse the Bezier path
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red:3/255, green:33/255, blue:70/255, alpha: 0.15).cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 2
        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
    
}
```

Use like this

myView.roundCornersWithBorder(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 8.0)

myView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 8.0)

Comment: doesn't work at all for the many reasons discussed extensively in the question