# How to apply border on view without losing image/view inside it?

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, border, nslayoutconstraint

I have requirement to apply border on views.

Views might have collection view or single image or textview. Now the problem is I want to apply border of those view. As I have used top, leading and width and height constraint and updating as border slider change the value but it behaves weird.

I have below view when app is loaded. [image: Image when loaded first time]

After applying constraint updates from loop, the views looks like [image: This after constraints update]

I am trying since 6 hours but the way of updating constrains to apply border not working so can any one suggest good approach to apply border without updating constraint of views?

Comment: What about `view.layer.borderWidth`?

Comment: I have applied, it worked fine but the image hide in back so I don't want to hide the image behind the border.

Comment: Try external border like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184133/add-a-border-outside-of-a-uiview-instead-of-inside.

Comment: I have tried this but as I have used NSLayoutConstraint, external border is not applied.

Comment: @Manish - I don't see *any* borders in the images you posted? Show an image of how you ***want*** it to look.